# Increment Big integer by 1 in Jython

Tags: python, jython

I have an attribute which has value stored in Big Integer and would like to increment it to 1. For example

```
 A = 2,000 
 B = A +1
```

I tried the following however resulted in syntax error.

```
  B = int(A) + 1 
  B = type(A)+1
```

Please note that 2,000 is a system generated number and we cannot modify the same

Comment: There is no syntax error in the second example. I'm sure it raises an exception, but I doubt it's related to syntax.

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(A))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = 2,000
```

This is not the number two thousand.  Because of the comma, it is a *tuple* `(2, 0)`.

Don't use commas as a thousands separator.

Assign the value without any separators:

```
A = 2000
```

Or you can use `_` as a separator:

```
A = 2_000
```

However, be aware that using `_` as a separator is purely cosmetic.  If you had mistyped the value as `2_00`, you would get a value of 200.

Comment: this is system generated number and we cannot change it. Hence need to find a way to increment it.

Comment: If you're getting a value of `2,000` from some other system,. then it must be a string.  Python does _not_ store numbers with commas.